# how to remove last part of string in c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, console-application

I was trying to remove last part of a string but failed.Here string named `D:\software\VS2012\newtext.txt` and i want to trim last section of string so here `newtext.txt` . I should get `D:\software\VS2012` but how to do it in c#.When i tried it is removing all the string that has '\'. Here is  what i did in c#

```
string str = @"D:\softwares\VS2012\newtext.txt";
           str= str.Remove(str.IndexOf('\\'));
            Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 11):

There is a premade function for this in the framework

```
string str = @"D:\softwares\VS2012\newtext.txt";
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(str);
```

([Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx))

Note that your original code does not work because you are removing from the first backslash, not the last.  Substitute this line to make your code work

```
str = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf('\\'));
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the original code could be modified to use str.SubString() to accomplish the same goal. However, the original suggestion of using the GetDirectoryName function is definitely more straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(string)`:

```
string dirname= System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(@"D:\softwares\VS2012\newtext.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

For removing a known portion of a string you can simply use the Replace.
In your case:

```
str = str.Replace("\\newtext.txt", ""); //this will give you the same result of the System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName already suggested by gmiley, but it's more in a string context as per your question
```

Though if you want to remove the last part of a string by the last encounterd known character then the suggested "LastIndexOff('\')" method already suggested along with the Remove.

If you want to use a delimiter method, so depending on the delimiter character but not on the string format (in your case path format) the LastIndexOff(char) is the best option.

Although you could also split the string into an array and then rejoin the array after removing the last element:

```
var delmimter = '\\';
var strAy = str.Split(char);
str = String.Join('\\', strAy.SkipLast(1).ToArray());
```

With this method you don't need to rely on the existence of the delimiter char in the string and the result is always without the delimiter char at the end.
Besides, you can easily create an extension with the delimiter as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

We should check the existance of the char also

```
string str = @"D:\softwares\VS2012\newtext.txt";

int rstr = str.LastIndexOf('\\');

if (rstr>0) str= str.Remove(rstr);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```